# Finding the solution of an equation and determining its degree

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is how to show that the solution set of this equation

$$\frac{1-{|x|}}{{|1+x|}}-1=0$$

is $(-1,0]$.

Please  explain what is the degree of this equation. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks,Mr zev chonoles to edit my post

Answer (score 2):

This can also be written as $|1+x| = 1- |x|$.

Do you know what conditions on two real numbers $a$ and $b$ imply that $|a+b| = |a| + |b|$?

Comment: In this case you could use $a = 1+x$ and $b = -x$.